# Error installing eZ publish platform

Tags: ezpublish, ezplatform

I am trying to install ezpublish platform [15.05.02](http://share.ez.no/downloads/downloads/ez-platform-15.05-alpha). When i run `composer update` i get the following error

```
[Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
The service "ezplatform.installer.install_command" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "search_engine". Di
d you mean one of these: "ezpublish.api.search_engine.class", "ezpublish.api.search_engine.factory.class", "ezpubli
sh.api.search_engine.default"?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `search_engine: legacy` to `ezpublish/config/parameters.yml` to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: might be that parameters.yml get overwritten by composer [link](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/642) so add "keep-outdated": true to extra section in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

Just a note here, you can now use eZ Launchpad to bootstrap your project on top of Docker very easily.
https://ezsystems.github.io/launchpad/